# Node.js mongodb email validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to validate the email address before update in mongodb. I'm a bit confused how to do that

```
var user = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
};
db.users.insert(user, function(err, newuser) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.send({
        status: 'success',
        data: newuser,
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you define any schema, e.g. using MongooseJS?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this link. [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

You can use HTML5 inbuilt feature:

HTML5 itself has email validation. If your browser supports HTML5 then you can use the following code.

```
<form><input type="email" placeholder="me@example.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can also use regular expressions for email validation

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: @NoamM I have updated my answer. The link is to a highly voted SO question which likely don't get deleted.